# How to import Flat-file with no column header using SSIS?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, flat-file, flatfilesource

I want to import the flat file using SSIS. My flat file has 50 columns but no column header. So it shows like Column 0, Column 1, and so on. I don't want to manually assign column name using the advanced editor. Is there a way to dynamically assign 50 column names. So that Column 0 = Client , Column 1 = Date and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Option 1 would be to install the BI Developer Extensions and use the "Create Fixed Width Columns" tool https://bideveloperextensions.github.io/features/CreateFixedWidthColumns/

Option 2 Define your flat file with [Biml](http://www.bimlscript.com/) and generate your package (and connection manager) there. I have [plenty of examples](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A181965+FlatFileFormat) of doing this in Biml

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @billinkc answer, there are other options if you are familiar with C#:

**(a) Using SQL Server Client SDK assemblies**

This is the official traditional way to create ssis packages programmatically, there are many link on the internet that you can refer to such as:

- [Creating a Package Programmatically](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/building-packages-programmatically/creating-a-package-programmatically?view=sql-server-2017)
- [Samples for creating SSIS packages programmatically](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mattm/2008/12/30/samples-for-creating-ssis-packages-programmatically/)
- [Creating and Executing an SSIS Package Programmatically](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/on-the-fringe/2013/08/25/creating-and-executing-an-ssis-package-programmatically/)
- [Building Packages Programmatically](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/building-packages-programmatically/building-packages-programmatically?view=sql-server-2017)

**(b) Using EzApi – Alternative package creation API**

> EzAPI is a .NET library written in C# by Evgeny Koblov one of the testers on the SSIS team to abstracts away a lot of the cumbersome low-level coding needed to create SSIS packages XML directly in a programming language

- [GitHub - EzApi2016](https://github.com/fpvmorais/EzApi2016)
- [NuGet Gallery - EzApi](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EzAPI/)

There are many link on the internet that you can refer to such as:

- [EzAPI – Alternative package creation API](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mattm/2008/12/30/ezapi-alternative-package-creation-api/)
- [EzAPI Overview](http://billfellows.blogspot.com/2012/01/ezapi-overview.html)
- [EzApi a C# library for creating SSIS packages programatically](https://www.kapacity.dk/ezapi-a-c-library-for-creating-ssis-packages-programatically/?lang=en)
- [Getting Started with EzAPI](https://www.dimodelo.com/blog/2013/getting-started-with-ezapi/)

**(c) Using SchemaMapper class library**

Recently i started a new project on Git-Hub, which is a class library developed using C#. You can use it to import tabular data from excel, word , powerpoint, text, csv, html, json and xml into SQL server table with a different schema definition using schema mapping approach. check it out at:

- [SchemaMapper: C# Schema mapping class library](https://github.com/munchy-bytes/SchemaMapper)

You can follow this Wiki page for a step-by-step guide:

- [Import data from multiple files into one SQL table step by step guide](https://github.com/munchy-bytes/SchemaMapper/wiki/Import-data-from-multiple-files-into-one-SQL-table-step-by-step-guide)

You can use this library to read from flat file and import into SQL with a few lines of code*.